# Title of 5 results in Google Maps

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I am trying to print the names of 5 first engineering schools from google maps. I have made the following code but I can't find out why there are no results after runing!

Can you help please?

Many thanks in advance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "L2AGLb").click()

driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps")

# Wait for the page to load and display the search box
time.sleep(3)

# Input the search query for "parisserie in Paris" and press Enter
search_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, "searchboxinput")
search_box.send_keys("engineering school in london")
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait for the search results to load
time.sleep(5)

# Get the names of the first 5 results using "aria-label"
results = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='place-result-container-place-link']/@aria-label")

# Print the names for debugging
for i, result in enumerate(results[:5], start=1):
    print(f"Result {i}: {result}")

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

I am trying to get some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete script (based on your settings), which goes directly to the URL with the search results, and uses a better selector for finding the school names:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/search/engineering+school+in+london")
time.sleep(5)
elements = driver.find_elements('css selector', '[role="main"] a[href*="google"]')
results = [element.get_attribute("aria-label") for element in elements]
for i, result in enumerate(results[:5], start=1):
    print(f"Result {i}: {result}")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** Your below XPath expression seems to be not correct, I don't see it locating any elements.

```
//a[@class='place-result-container-place-link']/@aria-label
```

**Check the below working code:**

```
search_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, "searchboxinput")
search_box.send_keys("engineering school in london")
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait for the search results to load
time.sleep(5)

# Get the elements based on the below XPath locator
results = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='hfpxzc']")

# Print the names for debugging
for i, result in enumerate(results[:5], start=1):
    print(f"Result {i}: {result.get_attribute('aria-label')}")

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

**Console output:**

```
Result 1: London Design and Engineering UTC
Result 2: UCL Faculty of Engineering Sciences
Result 3: School of Computing and Engineering
Result 4: Dyson School of Design Engineering, Imperial College London
Result 5: QMUL School of Engineering and Materials Science

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, I wonder by chance if you know how to scroll down the page in order to load more results? for example to get 15 engineering school.

Comment: Accept the answer if it has resolved your issue. That way it's not left unanswered. Regarding scrolling down the page, it's a separate issue. Keep one issue per question. I suggest create a new question with relevant code and explain the issue, this way you will get response from wider community.